# Some types of transitions not working, others working - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have an issue where I'm trying to use a transition for a button which appears when a certain condition is met. This button is overlaid on top of another view, and is anchored at the bottom. I want to make it slide up from the bottom when it appears, and slide back down when it disappears.

For that, I would use `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom).animation(.linear))`. However, it's simply not working -- it just pops into existence, and pops back out, without any sliding or animation.

Even more curious, the transition does have effect when I use `.opacity.animation(.linear)` or `.scale.animation(.linear)`, but doesn't work for any other transitions.

Here's what the code looks like:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        // ...
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        if condition {
            Button(action: { /* ... */ }) {
                Text("Share")
            }
            .background { LinearGradient(...) }
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).animation(.linear))
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why the transition only works with `.opacity` and `.scale`, and how I could make it work with `.move(edge: .bottom)`?

Answer (score 5):

Wrap condition into container, so there is a parent who can animate it, like

```
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
  VStack {                       // << here !!
    if condition {
        Button(action: { /* ... */ }) {
            Text("Share")
        }
        .background { LinearGradient(...) }
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
    }
  }
  .animation(.linear, value: condition)  // << important !!
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that didn't work, I get the same results – I also tried wrapping the ScrollView itself into a container, and that didn't work neither.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure it's not an issue with z-indexes neither, because if I make the animation last 10 seconds, it still pops up at the front instantly.

Comment: See updated - animation also should be on container - that is important part, and it was tested.

Comment: Works like a charm! Many thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I'm encountering another issue though – when the button disappears, it starts going down, but then it suddenly freezes for a quarter of a second, and finally goes back down all the way. Just like for the previous issue, it happens on all the transitions except `.opacity` and `.scale`.

[Here's](https://github.com/nikitamounier/tapit-app/blob/main/Sources/TapFeature/TapFeatureView.swift#L307-L324) the relevant code. Would you like me to maybe make a new SO post in case you'd want to see a screen recording of the strange behaviour?